# How can I find C1 and C2 from this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find C1 and C2 from C1*cos(pi/4) + C2*sin(pi/4) - 1/2 = 1/2? You can't compare... They said C1 = 0 and C2 = sqrt(2). I don't know how they got that. Please tell me how to find C1 and C2 in the most efficient and simplest way. Thank you

Comment: @kan what may be quite trivial to one person can be quite difficult for another...

Answer (score 4):

Since 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$
so your equality becomes
$$C_1+C_2=\sqrt 2$$
and obviously there's infinitely many choices of $C_1$ and $C_2$

Comment: So are you allowed to choose any?

Comment: Yes and your example $C_1=0$ and $C_2=\sqrt 2$ is a possible choice.